# NAnt MSBuild Version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, nant

Where is the configuration setting in nant that sets which version of MSBuild to use?

Nant wants to use 3.5 when it needs to use 4.0.

Comment: Why not using MSBuild natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog entry a few years ago that explains how to leverage any version of MSBuild from your NAnt build script. Essentially, you would be using the `<exec>` node to make the call to MSBuild as it is installed on your computer.

http://enterpriseyness.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-with-cruise-control-net-nant/

```
<target name=”build”>
  <exec program=”${MSBuildPath}”>
    <arg line=’”${SolutionFile}”‘ />
    <arg line=”/property:Configuration=${SolutionConfiguration}” />
    <arg value=”/target:Rebuild” />
    <arg value=”/verbosity:normal” />
    <arg value=”/nologo” />
    <arg line=’/logger:”C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll”‘/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a NAnt framework configuration. If you edit the NAnt.exe.config file make a duplicate of one of the `<framework>` elements with all it's children. Change the `frameworkdirectory` to use the version number of MSBuild you want to use. You can look at the other `<framework>` elements for the correct usage. For example if you wanted to have the 'net-3.5' `<framework>` element use MSBuild 4.0 just change the duplicated `<framework>` open element to look like:

```
<framework 
    name="net-3.5-msbuild-4.0"
    family="net"
    version="3.5"
    description="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 with MSBuild 4.0"
    sdkdirectory="${sdkInstallRoot}"
    frameworkdirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v4.0.30319')}"
    frameworkassemblydirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v2.0.50727')}"
    clrversion="2.0.50727"
    clrtype="Desktop"
    vendor="Microsoft"
    ><!-- Rest of framework contents here --></framework>
```

Note the different version number in the `frameworkdirectory` attribute.

Then specify the framework you want to use in NAnt.

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5-msbuild-4.0" />
```